# F# how to set content on WPF Label programmatically

Tags: wpf, f#

F# Code

```
open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls

let resourceLocator = new Uri("/ConsoleApplication3;component/MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative)

let lbl2 = (Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocator) :?> Window).FindName("lbl") :?> Label

let tb = (Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocator) :?> Window).FindName("tb") :?> TextBlock

let tbo = (Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocator) :?> Window).FindName("tbo") :?> TextBox

let value = "ROCK!"
let clickButton = fun _ -> 
    lbl2.Content <- "ROCK!"

let loadWindow() = 
    let resourceLocator = new Uri("/ConsoleApplication3;component/MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
    let window = Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocator) :?> Window
    (window.FindName("clickButton") :?> Button).Click.Add(clickButton)
    window

[<STAThread>]
(new Application()).Run(loadWindow()) |> ignore
```

My Xaml WPF Code:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <Button Name="clickButton" Content="Click  me!" Height="40" Width="150" />
        <Label Name="lbl" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="198,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBlock Name="tb" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="198,201,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBlock" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="tbo" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="340,198,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

I intend to change the content of a Label:lbl with a button click, but for some reason it is not working, but can't see why

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: On a side note, I'd **highly** recommend using FsXaml instead of doing this manually - it makes life much, much easier.  https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml

Comment: This is probably because the content of controls isn't a `string`, its a control. In the XAML, it parses the text into a control for you, but when you set it from code behind you will need to set the content as a control of some sort.

Comment: @DLeh Nope - you can set `Content` to anything.  It works the smae in code behind as xaml: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.content(v=vs.110).aspx  The default DataTemplate for a string will convert it to a `TextBlock`

Comment: Okay maybe it functions differently with F# then. I thought i had had issues setting content to a string in codebehind in C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem, in this case, is that you're loading the component more than once.  When you call `clickButton`, it's using the result of a bound value that was bound to a loaded window instance separate from the main instance.

You should be able to work around this, in this case, by using `Application.Current.MainWindow` to get the window that's already been displayed:

```
open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls

let resourceLocator = new Uri("/ConsoleApplication3;component/MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative)

// This needs to be a function, so it's not evaluated before the window is created
let getLbl2 () = Application.Current.MainWindow.FindName("lbl") :?> Label

let value = "ROCK!"
let clickButton = fun _ -> 
    let lbl = getLbl2()
    lbl.Content <- "ROCK!"

let loadWindow() = 
    let resourceLocator = new Uri("/ConsoleApplication3;component/MainWindow.xaml", UriKind.Relative)
    let window = Application.LoadComponent(resourceLocator) :?> Window
    (window.FindName("clickButton") :?> Button).Click.Add(clickButton)
    window

[<STAThread>]
(new Application()).Run(loadWindow()) |> ignore
```

That being said, I'd really recommend using [FsXaml](https://github.com/fsprojects/FsXaml/) to work with your WPF resources.  The type provider will provide you type safe access to your data, and make life far simpler.

This could be rewritten using FsXaml as:

```
open System
open System.Windows
open System.Windows.Controls
open FsXaml

type MainWindow = XAML<"MainWindow.xaml">

let loadWindow() = 
    let window = MainWindow().CreateRoot()
    let accessor = MainWindow.Accessor window
    accessor.clickButton.Click.Add(fun _ -> accessor.lbl.Content <- "ROCK!")
    window

[<STAThread>]
(new Application()).Run(loadWindow()) |> ignore
```

Note that when using `FsXaml`, you get full intellisense of your members, and you don't need the magic strings anymore.

Comment: Thanks, your code did not quite work, but with .Current added after Application and thanks for the tip about FsXaml, I will definitely look into that.

Comment: @user3874490 Added the .Current in ther e- that's what happens when you type directly in an answer sometimes :)